# Mapping from primtive type property to child object

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to use AutoMapper for the usual scenario Dto -> Entity. But one of the Dto's properties should map to my Entity's child.

My Employee DTO has a property of type int, JobTitleId. 
My Employee Entity has a child Entity JobTitle, which has an property of id. This is where i want to map to. So summarized it will be something like:

```
EmployeeDto.JobTitleId ---> Employee.JobTitle.Id
```

The only thing that worked for me was adding a Custom Automapper Resolver, but it gets too nasty when I need to do that for many different but similar scenarios.

```
class EmployeeDto
{
  int JobTitleId; 
}

Class Employee
{
  JobTitle jobTitle;
}

Class JobTitle
{
  int Id; 
}
```

I would like something similar to this:

```
public class EmployeeMapperProfiles : Profile
{
  public EmployeeMapperProfiles()
  {
    CreateMap<EmployeeDto, Employee>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.JobTitle.Id,
         opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.JobTitleId));    
  }
}
```

However, my result with this approach is:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Expression 'dest => dest.JobTitle.Id' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. You can use ForPath, a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead. (Parameter 'lambdaExpression')'.
```

But AfterMap and custom resolver approaches are not what I want.
So it must be ForPath, can't get it to work though.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Exception message is telling you that you cannot specify custom mapping rules for child object properties, like this:

```cs
CreateMap<EmployeeDto, Employee>()
    .ForMember(
        employee => employee.JobTitle.Id,
        options => options.MapFrom(employeeDto => employeeDto.JobTitleId));
```

That's because only top-level members are supported, and for deeper mapping you should use tools like value resolvers, type converters, explicit path configurations or additional mappings between types.

### Solution

To specify source property for `Id` of `Employee` you should use path configuration like you already figured it out. It's pretty straightforward, like this:

```cs
CreateMap<EmployeeDto, Employee>()
    .ForPath(
        employee => employee.JobTitle.Id,
        options => options.MapFrom(employeeDto => employeeDto.JobTitleId));
```